# Trying to compare Any? with String

Tags: json, swift

I am getting a JSON response with Alamofire to populate a TableView. Now I need to filter the received data comparing some of the fields with a TextField text, for example "nombre" with texto_buscado.text

This is the function that loads the TableView:

```
public func cargarDatos_filtrados (){
    //fetching data from web api
    Alamofire.request(URL_GET_DATA).responseJSON { response in
        self.directorios.removeAll()

        //getting json
        if let json = response.result.value {
            print (json)
            //converting json to NSArray
            let directorioArray : NSArray  = json as! NSArray

            //traversing through all elements of the array
            for i in 0..<directorioArray.count{
                let nom = (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "nombre")

                if (nom == texto_buscado.text){
                    //DO SOMETHING
                }

                self.directorios.append(DirectorioCompleto(
                    nombre: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "nombre") as? String,
                    apellidos: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "apellidos") as? String,
                    apodo: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "apodo") as? String,
                    cumple: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "cumple") as? String,
                    conyuge: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "conyuge") as? String,
                    cumple_conyuge: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "cumple_conyuge") as? String,
                    aniversario_bodas: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "aniversario_bodas") as? String,
                    empresa: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "empresa") as? String,
                    direccion_empresa: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "direccion_empresa") as? String,
                    tel_negocio: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "tel_negocio") as? String,
                    fecha_ingreso: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "fecha_ingreso") as? String,
                    num_rotario: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "num_rotario") as? String,
                    padrino: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "padrino") as? String,
                    direccion_casa: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "direccion_casa") as? String,
                    tel_casa: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "tel_casa") as? String,
                    celular: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "celular") as? String,
                    email: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "email") as? String,
                    email_privado: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "email_privado") as? String,
                    clasificacion: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "clasificacion") as? String,
                    imagen: (directorioArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "imagen") as? String
                ))
            }
        }

        //displaying data in tableview
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following warning message:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'String?'

at line

```
if (nom == texto_buscado.text){
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

Comment: *hint*: `as? String` is used elsewhere.

Comment: @user2864740, what do you mean?

Comment: What does `.. as? String` do? How might it be useful to put a "useful type of value" in `nom`?

Comment: @user2864740, you mean so:   if (nom as! String == self.texto_buscado.text) . ?

Comment: I would probably structure it as so: `let nom = ... as? String`. Then `nom` (which is now a variable *typed* as a String) represents a String or nada. Then the expression becomes [String] == [String] which is valid. There are a bunch of other improvements, but..

Comment: Don't use `NSArray` in Swift. Don't use `AnyObject`. Don't repeat `directorioArray[i] as AnyObject` so many times. Don't use `value(forKey:)` to get a value from a dictionary.

Comment: @user2864740 and don't use `as!` if you're not sure about the data type of the value. For example, I think `let directorioArray: NSArray = json as! NSArray` should be `let directorioArray: NSArray? = json as? NSArray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to improve your code.

- Don't use `NSArray` in Swift.
- Don't use `AnyObject`.
- Don't repeat `directorioArray[i] as AnyObject` so many times.
- Don't use `value(forKey:)` to get a value from a dictionary.

Use proper Swift types. Use variables to hold values that get repeated.

Since your data appears to be an array of dictionaries with String keys and String values, you can update your code as follows:

```
public func cargarDatos_filtrados (){
    //fetching data from web api
    Alamofire.request(URL_GET_DATA).responseJSON { response in
        self.directorios.removeAll()

        //getting json
        if let json = response.result.value as? [[String:String]] {
            print (json)

            //traversing through all elements of the array
            for dict in json {
                let nom = dict["nombre"]

                if (nom == texto_buscado.text){
                    //DO SOMETHING
                }

                self.directorios.append(DirectorioCompleto(
                    nombre: dict["nombre"],
                    apellidos: dict["apellidos"],
                    apodo: dict["apodo"],
                    cumple: dict["cumple"],
                    conyuge: dict["conyuge"],
                    cumple_conyuge: dict["cumple_conyuge"],
                    aniversario_bodas: dict["aniversario_bodas"],
                    empresa: dict["empresa"],
                    direccion_empresa: dict["direccion_empresa"],
                    tel_negocio: dict["tel_negocio"],
                    fecha_ingreso: dict["fecha_ingreso"],
                    num_rotario: dict["num_rotario"],
                    padrino: dict["padrino"],
                    direccion_casa: dict["direccion_casa"],
                    tel_casa: dict["tel_casa"],
                    celular: dict["celular"],
                    email: dict["email"],
                    email_privado: dict["email_privado"],
                    clasificacion: dict["clasificacion"],
                    imagen: dict["imagen"]
                ))
            }
        }

        //displaying data in tableview
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you rmaddy. And what would be the best way to implement a search inside the JSON response and load only the search results?

Comment: That's a whole new question.