# Searching JSON response to reload tableView

Tags: swift

As continuation of my previous question [Trying to compare Any? with String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917664/trying-to-compare-any-with-string)
I would like to know what should I implement to reload the tableview with the JSON response objects that meet the search criteria from a textfield input.

This is the current function:

```
public func cargarDatos_filtrados (){
        //fetching data from web api
        Alamofire.request(URL_GET_DATA).responseJSON { response in
            self.directorios.removeAll()

            //getting json
            if let json = response.result.value as? [[String:String]] {
                print (json)

                //traversing through all elements of the array
                for dict in json {
                    let nom = dict["nombre"]

                    if (nom == self.texto_buscado.text){
                       //DO SOMETHING
                    }


                    self.directorios.append(DirectorioCompleto(
                        nombre: dict["nombre"],
                        apellidos: dict["apellidos"],
                        apodo: dict["apodo"],
                        cumple: dict["cumple"],
                        conyuge: dict["conyuge"],
                        cumple_conyuge: dict["cumple_conyuge"],
                        aniversario_bodas: dict["aniversario_bodas"],
                        empresa: dict["empresa"],
                        direccion_empresa: dict["direccion_empresa"],
                        tel_negocio: dict["tel_negocio"],
                        fecha_ingreso: dict["fecha_ingreso"],
                        num_rotario: dict["num_rotario"],
                        padrino: dict["padrino"],
                        direccion_casa: dict["direccion_casa"],
                        tel_casa: dict["tel_casa"],
                        celular: dict["celular"],
                        email: dict["email"],
                        email_privado: dict["email_privado"],
                        clasificacion: dict["clasificacion"],
                        imagen: dict["imagen"]
                    ))

                }
            }

            //displaying data in tableview
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Guess you are using self.directorios to feed your table view.  Two questioins- are you filtering the results locally? or you send a  search string  to your REST API? In the former case, you will need to maintain a master data array, and have another array that actually holds filtered data as per your search text. In latter case, you anyway get the right results from server,   and load your table from the array of results you got from server.

Comment: On  a side note, your DirectorioCompleto is too complicated and takes so many arguments. You can simply pass the dictionary and hide all that extraction within DirectorioCompleto.

Comment: Keep 2 instances of DirectorioCompleto arrays, one original and one filtered, then simply use .filter for your filtered array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For searching into your directory, implement this. I am assuming that you have to search by key `nombre` and its a string.

put this code where do you want to perform searching.

```
 if let text = self.texto_buscado.text
            {
                let filteredArray = self.directorios.filter{$0.nombre.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(text) || $0.apellidos.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(text)}
```

or for exact matching

```
                let filteredArray = self.directorios.filter{$0.nombre == text || $0.apellidos == text}
            }
```

`filteredArray` as for searched result and use this array for reloading your `tableView`

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, and how could  I perform the search against more than one key? All objects are strings

Comment: Done that. Please check.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your proposal